# Listing loaded modules of executed Java applications

Tags: java

I'm looking for tools to list loaded modules of executed Java applications.
Sometimes, when same jar has located class path on other path, we know which can be used, but we want to get list of path exactly.
Please let us know any URL or info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To analyze any java application there is an built in tool with Oracle JDK called *Java Mission Control*,

You can analyze many number of statistic by using that tool as i understand you need classpath of running application which you can get using *JMC*

[image]

Detail:

- You have List of all the running application in current machine
- To open JMX (1) select *Start JMX console* from context menu
- Select system (2) from bottom tab
- (3) Look at the Class Path
- There are also other things to explore

If this is not which you want then you can explore for more.